# Error complex function ERFI(X): looking for alternative function representations?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, complex

I have some analytical results from a physics problem, where the Mathematica gives the results in terms of complex error function.  **I would like to explore another function representation using Mathematica**. Here it is the code for the function.

[image]

```
    U=(1/4+I/4)  1/k Sqrt[\[Pi]] /Sqrt[ k R]  E^(-((I k (R^2+L^2))/(2 R)))
    (-erfi((1/2+I/2) 1  /Sqrt[k  R]   
    (R-Sqrt[d^2+L^2]))-erfi((1/2+I/2) 1  /Sqrt[ k  R]     (Sqrt[d^2+L^2]+R))+erfi((1/2+I/2) 1  /Sqrt[k  R] (R-L))+erfi((1/2+I/2) 1  /Sqrt[ k  R] (R+L)))
```

For example for simplicity taking some values constants, let's say k = 1;  R = 1; d = 1;. It is possible to approximate using series, finally the real part is needed to have physical meaning and interpretation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why you need (or want) "another" representation instead? What is the purpose or form of such a representation?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica functions start with a capital letter, function definitions need square brackets! Change  `erfi( ...)` to `Erfi[ ... ]`

```
U = (1/4 + I/4) 1/k Sqrt[\[Pi]]/
   Sqrt[k R] E^(-((I k (R^2 + L^2))/(2 R)))
(-Erfi[(1/2 + I/2) 1/Sqrt[k R] (R - Sqrt[d^2 + L^2])] - 
  Erfi[(1/2 + I/2) 1/Sqrt[k R] (Sqrt[d^2 + L^2] + R)] + 
  Erfi[(1/2 + I/2) 1/Sqrt[k R] (R - L)] + 
  Erfi[(1/2 + I/2) 1/Sqrt[k R] (R + L)])
```

real part of `U`

```
ComplexExpand[Re[U]]:

(*
(Sqrt[\[Pi]] (k^2 R^2)^(3/4)
   Cos[(k (L^2 + R^2))/(2 R)] Cos[1/2 Arg[k R]])/(4 k^3 R^2) + (
 Sqrt[\[Pi]] (k^2 R^2)^(3/4)
   Cos[1/2 Arg[k R]] Sin[(k (L^2 + R^2))/(2 R)])/(4 k^3 R^2) + (
 Sqrt[\[Pi]] (k^2 R^2)^(3/4)
   Cos[(k (L^2 + R^2))/(2 R)] Sin[1/2 Arg[k R]])/(4 k^3 R^2) - (
 Sqrt[\[Pi]] (k^2 R^2)^(3/4)
   Sin[(k (L^2 + R^2))/(2 R)] Sin[1/2 Arg[k R]])/(4 k^3 R^2)
```

*)

Comment: Or `ComplexExpand[Re[U], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // FullSimplify`

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(altRep = Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Erfi"][
    "AlternativeRepresentations"]) // Column
```

[image]

```
(altRep2 = (#[z] & /@ altRep // Activate) /. 
    True -> Nothing) // Column
```

[image]

To make one into a replacement rule:

```
(#[[1]] /. z -> z_) -> #[[-1]] &@altRep2[[-2]]

(* Erfi[z_] -> (Sqrt[-z^2] (-1 + GammaRegularized[1/2, -z^2]))/z *)
```